# Some definitions beyond my major in algorithms or acoustic area about seismic wave handling in geophysics

Tags: algorithm, acoustics

I am handling seismic waves after stacking them: S(x,y,t), in which x,y is the known epicenter locations and t is the variable: time.
the following steps will be these:

> (...) we apply a space-time smoothing operator to *S(x,y,t)*. We use a scaling speed of 3 km/s to convert time to pseudo-space, and integrate *S(x,y,t)*<sup>2</sup> with a running cube operator of width *d<sub>c</sub>* resulting in *S<sub>i</sub>(x,y,t)*<sup>2</sup>. This operator preserves energy that travels through *S(x,y,t)* at slow speeds (such as the constructively interfering energy that delineates the rupture), but helps attenuate artifacts that sweep through at the faster speeds of the direct P phase. (...)

I wonder that from the sentence"we apply....",how to convert the waveform from temporal to pseudo-space and what is the running cube operator?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming as defined in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: OK, the content is "we apply a space-time" smoothing operator to S(x,y,t). We use a scaling speed of 3km/s to convert time to pseudo-space, and integrate S(x,y,t)^2 with a running cube operator of width dc,resulting in Si(x,y,t)^2.